# Create unit test for events

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm using the following open source for unzip the files which is working OK.

Now I want to create some **integration test** for it to see that the file was saved,the problem is that the process is trowing **events** and I don't know for sure when the process end,any idea how to solve this?
ex

```
var DecompressZip = require('decompress-zip');
var unzipper = new DecompressZip(filename)

unzipper.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Caught an error');
});

unzipper.on('extract', function (log) {
    console.log('Finished extracting');
});

unzipper.on('progress', function (fileIndex, fileCount) {
    console.log('Extracted file ' + (fileIndex + 1) + ' of ' + fileCount);
});

unzipper.extract({
    path: 'some/path',
    filter: function (file) {
        return file.type !== "SymbolicLink";
    }
});
```

I use mocha & chai as test framework.
and this is the open source
https://github.com/bower/decompress-zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocha [support asynchronous code](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) you need to call test case with `done` argument and then once all checks is completed call `done` function.

Example:

```
var DecompressZip = require('decompress-zip');


describe("Unzipper test", function() {
  it("should extract folder without error", function(done) { 
    var unzipper = new DecompressZip(filename);

    unzipper.on('error', done); // Pass error to done callback

    unzipper.on('extract', function (log) {
      // Add your checks

      done();
    });
  });

  unzipper.extract({
    path: 'some/path',
    filter: function (file) {
      return file.type !== "SymbolicLink";
    }
  });
});
```